# Session termination in single logout using SAML

Tags: session, single-sign-on, logout, saml-2.0

Let us say we have a user who is accessing three different services using `Single sign-on`.
On clicking on Logout the session with current Sp can be identified and terminated.

Here on, it is the responsibility of `IdP` to log the user out from the other two services.
My question is how the sessions with the remaining two services will be obtained and terminated?

Answer (score 7):

The Idp send the other two SPs a LogoutRequest with the sessionIndex of the user to be logged out. The SPs are then responsible to terminate the session on their side.

Comment: But this session index has to be given to the IdP at the time of SSO and a database is to be maintained for each (SP+user) combination. is there a more scalable way?

Comment: The session index is given to the SP from the IDP at sign on. At SLO the SP send the session index of the user. As far as i know the SP need to keep track of (SAML session index, Java session) for each user. And the IDP needs to keep track of uid and the session index for each SP. As far as i know there is no other way.

Comment: @Shurmajee - out of curiosity, how come you haven't accepted this answer? I battled SAML, this answer proved useful, as it helped me implement SLO easily.

Comment: @Mjh I have up-voted this answer as it is technically correct. however back in 2013 I was trying to come up with a simple solution with minimal integration efforts as our target SPs were having kinda legacy systems. There were resistant to any major changes and hence I could not really implement the SLO feature.

Comment: @Shurmajee fair enough, thanks for taking the time to reply :)

Answer (score 3):

During SSO, IDP sends SAML Assertion to SP that contains AuthnStatement. One of the attributes of this AuthnStatement is SessionIndex that identifies the session of the user with the IDP.

During SLO, SP sends SAML Logout Request that contains SessionIndex that identifies the session of the user (with the IDP) that the IDP must terminate. IDP then retrieves the list of SPs that participate in the current user session. IDP sends SAML Logout Request to each of these SPs.

In order to do this, IDP needs to keep track of the SPs that participate in the current user session (i.e., the SPs that received SAML Assertion issued by the IDP during the current user session).

Comment: Right but the user is having multiple active sessions.and logout should terminate all the sessions.stefans answer does the trick but I was wondering if there is a better way possible